Laravel repository method helper file is not loaded
i am using folder structure like
project/
    project-repository/
        src/
            User/
                UserInterface.php
                UserRepository.php
        composer.json        
    project-services/
        src/
            User/
                UserService.php
        Helper/
            helpers.php        
        composer.json 
    laravel/
        app/
        config/
        public/
        ...
    composer.json

and my repositories folder json is
{
    "name": "project/project-repository",
    "description": "A Laravel repository package.",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Repository\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "DEvLoPER"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}

and my services folder json is
{
    "name": "project/project-services",
    "description": "A Laravel Services package",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0", 
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Service\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
             "Helper/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "DEvLoPER"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}

in my laravel folder json is
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../project-repository"
    },
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../project-service"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^4.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
    "project/project-repository": "^1.0",
    "project/project-service": "^1.0"
},

In service folder i create a helper folder and helper file i wand access that helper functions from service's file in json i include that but not working showing
Call to undefined function Service\User\curlPostRequest()   here curlPostRequest() is helper function in service file i call $data = curlPostRequest().
How we can achive this i try many time.

from the services folder json file i remove this line
"files": [
             "Helper/helpers.php"
        ]

and iclude in main laravel project jsonfile like
 "files": [
                 "../project-services/Helper/helpers.php"
            ]

